# Table is not modified outside of getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to write an app to let people track their fishing results in the Final Fantasy XIV MMO. You select different types of fish and bait, and the application generates a matrix of input fields to record what fish bite on what bait, and the results eventually being compiled in a database.

I started with some PHP scripts that simply barf out some example JSON for fish and bait, wrote the below, and it seemed to generate the table just fine. However, I want users to be able to add new fish and bait at will, so I added a couple manual calls to `addFish()` and `addBait()` at the bottom and found that these do not work.

Even when the `getJSON()` calls are commented out the manual call do not appear to work. I've tried changing the order of the calls, in case there's something squiffy in one of my functions, but still nothing.

Can anyone spot the reason why these calls are not adding the fields to the table?

- Baits are defined by the IDs of the header cells.
- Fish are defined by the IDs of the rows.
- Adding a new Fish grabs the bait IDs and appends a new row to the table.
- Adding a new Bait appends a new cell to the header row, and to each Fish row.

If there's any other info I can provide please let me know.

Source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thing!</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function genCell(fid, bid) {
            cellid = "matrix-"+fid+"-"+bid
            infield = "<input class='fishnum' type='text' name='"+cellid+"' />"
            return "<td class='fishnum' id='"+cellid+"'>"+infield+"</td>"
        }
        function addFish(id, name) {
            console.log('addFish: '+id+','+name)
            baits = []
            $("#fishtable").find("td[id|='bait']").each(function(){
                baitid = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]
                cellid = "matrix-"+id+"-"+baitid
                baits[baits.length] = genCell(id, baitid)
            })
            $("#fishtable").append(
                "<tr id='fish-"+id+"'><td><p class='sidelabel'>"+name+"</p></td>"+baits.join('')+"</tr>")
        }
        function addBait(id, name) {
            console.log('addBait: '+id+','+name)
            $("#fishtableheader").append("<td id='bait-"+id+"'><p class='toplabel'>"+name+"</p></td>")
            $("#fishtable").find("tr[id|='fish']").each(function(){
                fishid = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]
                cellid = "matrix-"+fishid+"-"+id
                $(this).append(genCell(fishid, id))
            })
        }

        // these will generate the table just fine
        $.getJSON("api/v1/bait.php", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key,val) {
                addBait(key, val['name'])
            })
        })
        $.getJSON("api/v1/fish.php", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key,val) {
                addFish(key, val['name'])
            })
        })
        // these do nothing
        addBait(5, 'Spinning Lure')
        addBait(7, 'Chocobo Fly')
        addFish(4, 'Lamprey')
        addFish(6, 'Plaguefish')

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<table id="fishtable" class="fishtable">
    <tr id="fishtableheader"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<h2>Debug</h2>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Generated Table from DOM source:

```
<table id="fishtable" class="fishtable"><tbody>
    <tr id="fishtableheader"><td>&nbsp;</td><td id="bait-1"><p class="toplabel">Crab Ball</p></td><td id="bait-2"><p class="toplabel">Goby Ball</p></td><td id="bait-3"><p class="toplabel">Bass Ball</p></td></tr>
    <tr id="fish-1"><td><p class="sidelabel">Moat Carp</p></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-1-1"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-1-1" type="text"></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-1-2"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-1-2" type="text"></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-1-3"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-1-3" type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr id="fish-2"><td><p class="sidelabel">Rainbow Trout</p></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-2-1"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-2-1" type="text"></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-2-2"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-2-2" type="text"></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-2-3"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-2-3" type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr id="fish-3"><td><p class="sidelabel">Spotted Pleco</p></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-3-1"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-3-1" type="text"></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-3-2"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-3-2" type="text"></td><td class="fishnum" id="matrix-3-3"><input class="fishnum" name="matrix-3-3" type="text"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Console Log:

```
addBait: 5,Spinning Lure
addBait: 7,Chocobo Fly
addFish: 4,Lamprey
addFish: 6,Plaguefish
addBait: 1,Crab Ball
addBait: 2,Goby Ball
addBait: 3,Bass Ball
addFish: 1,Moat Carp
addFish: 2,Rainbow Trout
addFish: 3,Spotted Pleco
```

Comment: Seems to work okay here:  http://jsfiddle.net/h1pbmzs5/1/ or here: http://jsfiddle.net/h1pbmzs5/

Comment: Yeah same here man, click on "Crab Ball".  http://jsfiddle.net/seano666/cgswo3nf/

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser and step through your code line-by line. Optimally, do this *before* posting on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as @james-montagne and @seano666 seem to have had no trouble making this work in JSfiddle I did some further testing and found that the trouble seems to have been that my code was trying to run:

1. Before the DOM fully loaded.
2. Occasionally before JQuery loaded.

Based on my Googlings wrapping my code thusly appears to solve the issue:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("hello world")
        $.getJSON("api/v1/bait.php", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key,val) {
                addBait(key, val['name'])
            })
        })

        $.getJSON("api/v1/fish.php", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key,val) {
                addFish(key, val['name'])
            })
        })
        addBait(5, 'Spinning Lure')
        addBait(7, 'Chocobo Fly')
        addFish(4, 'Lamprey')
        addFish(6, 'Plaguefish')
    })
```